# world cup probability

Tags: probability

There are $4$ teams in a world cup group and $2$ of the $4$ qualify for the next round. If the probability of team $A$ qualifying for the next round is $A$ and the probability of team $B$ qualifying is $B$, then what is the probability of BOTH teams qualifying?

It cannot just  be $A \times B$ since the $2$ events are not independent, but I don't know how to calculate the adjustment for the correlation.

World Cup group stage qualification rules:  $4$ teams each playing the other $3$ once ($6$ games in total), $3$ pts for a win and $1$ pt for a draw, the $2$ teams with most points qualify for the next stage.

Comment: Well...how do the qualification rules work?  If, say, teams $A,B$ play an elimination round against each other then the answer is $0$. If, on the other hand, $A$ plays an elimination match agains $C$ and $B$ plays against $D$ then the answer is the product after all.   More broadly, we need information on the dependence between the events.

Comment: I don't believe there is enough information here for anyone to give much help.  Maybe the qualification of both teams depends on a common external event (like a rival team losing their next match).

Comment: Sorry Lulu, I just assumed everyone would know how the world cup group stage works: 4 teams each playing the other 3 once (6 games in total), 3 pts for a win and 1 pt for a draw, the 2 teams with most points qualify for the next stage.

Comment: Maybe everyone (but me) does!  But with the rules you describe, it becomes clear that the problem can't be answered as stated, since $A's$ triumph might come at $B's$ expense.

Answer (score 0):

This would be.....$$\frac{AB}{AB+AC+AD+BC+BD+CD}$$ Your question should have included the information about the probability of C and D.

Comment: That works I believe .... it certainly delivers the correct answer for the easy case of 4 equal teams. Thank you.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say.  It could be that $D$ is much better than all the rest, will certainly win all its games, and qualify.  Then the chance both A and B qualify is zero.  If in addition C is weak we have $A+B=1$ because each one qualifying depends on the result of their match.  On the other hand, A and B could be sure to win against C and D and be sure to qualify.

Comment: So if we put D=1, C=0, A=B=0.5 into Phil's equation we get P(A and B both qualify) = 0.2 which is clearly incorrect if D=1. Well spotted. So the answer relies on D & C but not quite as Phil has it. Any further thoughts?

Comment: @RichardBentley:  I don't think the individual odds of A and B are enough.  Certainly if you have the odds of each game it is.  Where in between you can do something reasonable, I don't know.

Comment: Lets assume we DO know A, B, C and D. Can we form an equation from those 4 values without having to consider individual games? This looks like it should be easy but I'm struggling.